# Remove all columns between two column names in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm looking for a simple way to remove all columns between two columns in a dataframe in R.

So let's say I have a dataframe like so:

```
> test = data.frame('a' = 'a', 'b' = 'b', 'c'= 'c', 'd' = 'd', 'e' = 'e')
> test
  a b c d e
1 a b c d e
```

I'd like to be able to do the following in a dplyr chain

```
test %>% delete_between(a,c)
>test
   d e
 1 d e
```

Comment: Something different from `select(test, -a:-c)`?

Comment: Please study `?select`: Useful Functions [...] like `:`; `select(df, V4:V6)`; To drop variables, use `-`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use

```
test %>% 
   select(-(a:c))
```

Comment: Didn't realize you can use a colon in the select operator!  Thanks!